# Npm error when installing a npm addon for discord bot

Tags: visual-studio, discord.js, npm-install

Hello im trying to install wokcommands for my discord bot.using the terminal command but i keep getting this error

````
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "⌃4.4.2": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.```
````

Comment: Could you please specify what command are you trying to use and show us your package.json file?

Comment: npm install wokcommands

Comment: package.json file
`{
  "name": "discordbot-redone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon index.ts",
    "type": "module"
    
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
 "typescript": "⌃4.4.2"
 
}
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried downloading module you wanted to install and it works fine for me, so it's not npm problem. You can try removing "`,  "devDependencies": {  "typescript": "⌃4.4.2"   }`" from your package.json file because I can't see anything else with version "⌃4.4.2"

Comment: I'm glad I helped you!